# Best way to subtract SUM and COUNT with 2 table select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have came up with solution to count total of fields based on specific group, but it looks quite lengthy to get to the result i expect.
I have some basic knowledge when it comes to sql.

Is there obvious improvements to be made and why?
Why i would like to shorten this: Easier to implement in ORM type systems.

Changing scheme is not an option.

Schema and sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62df6

Query i'm using:

```
SELECT s.release_id,
       (s.shipments_total - IFNULL(sh.shipment_entries, 0)) AS shipments_left
FROM
  ( SELECT release_id,
           SUM(shipments) AS shipments_total
   FROM subscriptions
   WHERE is_paid = 1
     AND shipments > 1
   GROUP BY release_id ) AS s
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT release_id,
           COUNT(*) AS shipment_entries
   FROM shipments
   GROUP BY release_id ) AS sh ON s.release_id = sh.release_id
```

Expected result on sample data is in sqlfiddle.

Comment: Your query looks fine.  It is aggregating along each dimension separately (shipments and subscriptions), so the values should also be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bring the condition in-line and remove the `group by`, then you don't need `ifnull()`:

```
   SELECT s.release_id,
          (SUM(s.Shipments) -
           (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM shipments sh
            WHERE sh.release_id = s.release_id
           )
          ) AS shipments_left
   FROM subscriptions s
   WHERE is_paid = 1 AND shipments > 1
   GROUP BY s.release_id;
```

The subquery returns `0` if nothing matches, not `NULL` (with the `GROUP BY`, it would return `NULL`).  I am not sure if this is easier with your ORM model.  Your original version is fine from a SQL point of view.

Comment: Thanks, getting rid of ifnull and extra group by certainly helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can bring the join inline instead:

```
   SELECT s.release_id,
     SUM(s.Shipments) - IFNULL(( SELECT COUNT(*) AS shipment_entries 
                                 FROM shipments sh
                                 WHERE sh.release_id = s.release_id
                                 GROUP BY sh.release_id ), 0) AS shipments_left
   FROM subscriptions s
   WHERE is_paid = 1
     AND shipments > 1
   GROUP BY s.release_id
```

The execution plan for this is more performant too.

Comment: Thanks for solution, i choose other answer because of it removed couple of thing, tho your query is same in terms of performance it seems.